# how to make colors output using python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode, terminal

i'm new to python (about a week or less) and I'm using python 2.7.

i'm writing a program to check ip validation and classes and i want to make the output in color, so it will be more readable on terminal to the user.

i have already tried this:

```
# to make the text purple for example.
print '\033[95m' + "This is a purple output"
# if i'm writing another simple print after the first one it will be purple too
print "Example" # now this statement purple too
```

but when i use this example the output after the first print method become purple too.

Thank for everyone who try.

Comment: You can do like this : print '\033[95m' + "This is a purple output" + '\033[0m'

Comment: ohh i didn't see that post. sorry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By printing escape code `\033[0m`, you can reset the color:

```
>>> print '\033[95m' + "This is a purple output" + '\033[0m'
This is a purple output
```

Alternatively, you can use [`colorama` package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/colorama):

```
>>> from colorama import Fore
>>> print Fore.LIGHTMAGENTA_EX + "This is a purple output" + Fore.RESET
This is a purple output
```

Comment: thank you but i need a better way more efficient.

Comment: @shemesh, How do you define efficient ?

Comment: i think this '\033[95m' are not necessary, i mean that it's doesn't look that good when you read the code. can i use class with all the values of the colours ?

Comment: @shemesh, I add an alternative solution using a third-party package `colorama`. Check it out.

Comment: thank you man check out my solution, thanks to your help.

Comment: @shemesh, As I commented to your solution, no need to define a class if you use `colorama` package.

Answer (score 2):

well i think this is the best way i could think of.

```
class FontColors:
    def __init__(self):
        self.PURP = '\033[95m'
        self.LIGHTBLUE = '\033[94m'
        self.ENDC = '\033[0m'
        self.UNDERLINE = '\033[4m'
        self.LIGHTYELL = '\033[92m'
        self.BYELL = '\033[93m'
        self.FRED = '\033[91m'
        self.BOLD = '\033[1m'

color = FontColors()

# you can try like this - **the color.ENDC meant to make the output normal again.**
print "{0}This is a Purple output{1}".format(color.PURP, color.ENDC)
# or like this
print color.BYELL + "This is a Yellow output" + color.ENDC
```

Thank you @falsetru for helping me with this problem.

Comment: You don't need to defined them yourself. Check my updated answer.

Comment: got it man thank you. i would vote you up but i can't yet.

Comment: Could you please share any reference to all the color codes ?